# kubectl exec command failing with: Upgrade request required

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, rancher

I have set up a Rancher k8s environment on AWS.

Rancher server lies behind a classic ELB with ssl termination and is accessible via e.g `https://my.rancher.server`.

I have deployed a simple pod via the command line by running

```
kubectl create -f <podfilename.yml>
```

I am then able to `get` and `describe` the pod.

However, the following command fails:

```
$ kubectl exec my.pod.name -- ls /app
W1219 12:13:12.053543   16174 http.go:363] Error reading backend response: unexpected EOF
error: error sending request: Post https://my.rancher.server/r/projects/1a1043/kubernetes:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/my.pod.name/exec?command=ls&command=%2Fapp&container=k8s-demo&container=k8s-demo&stderr=true&stdout=true: unexpected EOF
```

**edit**: this is the json returned:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "Upgrade request required",
  "reason": "BadRequest",
  "code": 400
}
```

I have configured my elb to use ssl listener, and also configured proxy protocol.

[image]

Comment: Hi , could you try this `kubectl exec my.pod.name  ls /app`? I assumed there is only one container inside the pod

Comment: same result....

Comment: Hi, could you add the result of following command `kubectl exec  my.pod.name  ls /app -v 7` ?

Comment: Check out this gist: https://gist.github.com/pkaramol/0c389831f301ee14f390809d7684dd84

Comment: Thanks, If you could apply the same command to another pod. It seems to me Container is not responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ELB's HTTP does not support websockets; you need to use a SSL listener -> TCP backend and configure proxy protocol support. http://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.6/en/installing-rancher/installing-server/basic-ssl-config/#elb